# Проблема с сигналами между QML и С++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Проблема состоит в том, как отследить сигнал при смене песни в QMediaPlayer::durationChanged и это значение установить в Slider через свойство to?

MainWindwow.cpp

```
//Включаем наш QML
ui = new QQuickWidget;
ui->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
setCentralWidget(ui);
ui->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);

//Находим корневой элемент
Root = ui->rootObject();
//Соединяем C++ и QML, делая видимым функции С++ через элемент window
ui->rootContext()->setContextProperty("window", this);

AppController appcontroller;
ui->rootContext()->setContextProperty("app", &appcontroller);
```

Моя попытка установить соединение состоялась в том, чтобы создать новый класс, благодаря которому, будет происходить отправка сигнала:

Вот пример такого класса:

appcontroller.h

```
#ifndef APPCONTROLLER_H
#define APPCONTROLLER_H

#include <QObject>

#include <iostream>

class AppController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit AppController(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    // Сигнал для передачи данных в qml-интерфейс
    void sendToQml(qint64 value);

public slots:
    // Слот для приёма данных из c++
    void receiveFromC(qint64 value);

};

#endif // APPCONTROLLER_H
```

appcontroller.сpp

```
#include "appcontroller.h"

AppController::AppController(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void AppController::receiveFromC(qint64 value)
{
    emit sendToQml(value);
}
```

Так же конект в qml:

main.qml

```
Connections
{
    target: app
    onSendToQml:
    {
        slider.position = value
    }
}
```

Но все равно конект не происходит.

```
connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::durationChanged, appcontroller, &AppController::receiveFromC);
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял, зачем сигнал цеплять к сигналу? Чего Вы пытаетесь добиться?

Comment: Я хочу отправить сигнал из С++ в слот в моем файле QML.

Comment: Ну, после обновления код похож на правильный. Теперь проходитесь по нему отдладчиком и проверяйте, что не работает, потому что сходу сложно сказать. В QML можете использовать `console.log("Blah blah")` для помощи в отладке.

Comment: Короче, как обычно все оказалось намного проще чем, я думал. Главное от чего я отказался это от класса appcontroller. Почему то с ним ну никак не происходит конект. Я просто в MainWindwow все это реализовал, а именно, тупо добавил сигнал и слот из того класса и все работает как надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому-нибудь понадобится.

Чтобы отправить сигнал из C++ кода в qml-интерфейс я добавил в свой основной класс Mainwindow дополнительный сигнал и слот. Слот был нужен для принятия значения, а сигнал соответственно - для передачи этого значения:

MainWindow.h

```
signals:
    void sendValueToQml(qint64 value);

public slots:
    void takeValue(qint64);
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::takeValue(qint64 value)
{
    emit sendValueToQml(value);
}
```

Ну и сам конект (Дополнительно, я `value` прописал еще и в самом классе):

```
connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::positionChanged, this, &MainWindow::takeValue);
```

Теперь в сам qml файл нужно добавить следующее
( Где `window` подключается через контекст `ui->rootContext()->setContextProperty("window", this);` )

```
Connections
{
    target: window
    onSendValueToQml: slider.value = value
}
```

И тут есть небольшая хитрость с написанием самого сигнала. Во-первых название сигнала должно начинаться не с `on` и с большой буквы (Желательно). И затем в `Connections` нужно записать:
on + название сигнала с большой буквы. Допустим:

```
signalToQml - на C++
onSignalToQml - на QML
```

И прелесть вся в том, что можно создавать множество различных сигналов и слотов. И потом просто добавлять все в  `Connections`.